# Passing a PHP Variable in external JS file

Tags: php, javascript, variables, iframe

I've read lots of thread on here but I am still unable to get a variable passed from PHP to an external JS file and wondered if someone could assist?

In my PHP file I have the following;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pass_this_variable = <?php $company['website']; ?>;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/track.js"></script>
```

In the JS file I have the following;

```
document.write('<IFRAME SRC="$company['website']" WIDTH="300" HEIGHT="400"></IFRAME>');
```

What I am trying to achieve is an IFRAME be opened and populated with what is contained within $company['website']. I know I can just use IFRAME directly in the PHP file, but this isn't what I have been tasked with for my homework. When I do use IFRAME directly in the PHP file it works fine, and if I specify a static URL in the JS file such as http://www.google.com this also works fine.

Can anyone assist? Thanks

---

EDIT:

Thanks for the answers so far, however I'm still unable to get it working :(

The frame that I have in track.php (or track.js) won't load the url thats specified in `$company['website']`, yet if I change it to http://www.google.com its working fine. For some reason the `$company['website']` value isn't being passed :(

Comment: I would appreciate if you specified what happened when you tried my solution. I've tried and confirmed my example with different `<?php $company['website']="http://www.example.com/"; ?>` in the PHP file.

Answer (score 9):

if you want your external javascript to be dynamic you can make it a php file and give the correct header, example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/track.php"></script>
```

track.php

```
<?php
// javascript generator
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
?>
document.write('<IFRAME SRC="<?php echo $company['website'] ?>" WIDTH="300" HEIGHT="400"></IFRAME>');
```

Answer (score 6):

PHP file (don't forget echo and quoting):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pass_this_variable = '<?php echo $company['website']; ?>';
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/track.js"></script>
```

JS file (use pass_this_variable instead):

```
document.write('<IFRAME SRC="'+pass_this_variable+'" WIDTH="300" HEIGHT="400"></IFRAME>');
```

Comment: What if the company's name is "Joe's bar"? :-)

Comment: @Denis I believe a proper URL should be encoded with %27 instead of using single-quotes (reserved). Therefore, it won't matter in my example. However, it is always a good habit to think of line breaks, quotes etc. in strings.

Answer (score 2):

You should fix this line:
`var pass_this_variable = <?php echo $company['website']; ?>;`

Adding `echo` and it should work

Answer (score 2):

Call a PHP file inside the JavaScript source. You can find the tutorial here:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/externalphp.shtml.

So your code will be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="track.php?company=<?php echo $company['website']; ?>"></script>
```

In the PHP file you can fetch the value through `$_GET` variable and use it in the **iframe**. Make sure to sanitize the input.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript provides you the functionality of ajax for the purpose of reading the PHP or text files. Why don't you create the HTML `iframe` inside a PHP file with your variables parsed and then take back the response and "throw" it inside a div.

Comment: "JavaScript provides you the functionality of ajax"? AJAX *is* JavaScript. That's what the J stands for.

Answer (score 2):

The code for your PHP file:

```
$cmp = $company['website'];
echo '<input type="hidden" id="cmp1" name="cmp1" value="' . $cmp . '" />';
```

The code for your JavaScript (.js) file to get the PHP file value:

```
var company = document.getElementById('cmp').value;
```