# php constants in a javascript file

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pass a PHP string to a Javascript variable (and escape newlines)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines)

I'm working on a project and it's already done, but it needs one more midification and its applying language constants in javascript files.

consider we include a javascript file  and in that we have something like this

```
            alert("YOU Have VOTED BEFORE");
```

easy like that , the script will alert that text

but what if we need to alert a language constant of it :

```
            alert("<?php echo _VOTED_BEFORE?>");
```

this will be worked only if echo the script like inline of my php codes ...

but, how can we read and include php constants or $vars for a outside JavaScript file ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way of doing this using a query string in the script path

See my answer here

[How to pass variable from php template to javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260902/how-to-pass-variable-from-php-template-to-javascript/6260992#6260992)

Unfortunately this will break the cache for your js file so weight your options first

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js?flag=<?php echo _VOTED_BEFORE?>"></script>
```

for the sake of not writing too much code refer to the link to see how to retrieve the value

Comment: +1 for the question, not necessarily for the solution :)

Comment: shortest answer and the coolest one in my eye .. thanks bro

Comment: hey in javascript file , how can i read the vars ?

Comment: by reading the script src property and splitting the string. Follow the link above

Answer (score 12):

For a cleaner structure, I think the best way is to set all the data you get from PHP in one place, i.e. in the HTML you serve via PHP:

```
<script>
    var MyNameSpace = {
        config:
            something: "<?php echo _VOTED_BEFORE ?>"
        }
    }
</script>
```

In the JavaScript file you include afterwards, you can access the value via `MyNameSpace.config.something`.

This makes it also easier to reuse the message.

Comment: Awesome way to handle PHP/Javascript constants.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If it's not a PHP file, you cannot include PHP echo functions in it. I suggest that if you want to use a PHP variable in your external js files then declare it as a global in your PHP 
file before you reference the external js.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var globalvar = '<?php echo _VOTED_BEFORE ?>' ;    
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="externalfile.js"></script>
```

Though it's not always a good idea to clutter the global namespace.

Comment: You would need to quote that either on the client or on the server

Comment: @mplungjan - What do you mean?

Comment: He means that echoing _VOTED_BEFORE will output a string which will produce a syntax error in javascript if you dont wrap it into quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, what you had was close to being proper.

```
 <?php
 // Valid constant names
 define("VOTED_BEFORE", "false");
 ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("<?php echo VOTED_BEFORE;?>");
</script>
```

Comment: If the initial js is included through script tag this won't work.

Answer (score -1):

You can use cookies to save these constants and read them in via JavaScript or you will have to use AJAX

Comment: What a horrific idea to send all possible translations around in a cookie or to waste requests when all you have to do is to make the js file a php file with a mime type

Comment: He said that he already is aware of doing inline... read his question carefully"this will be worked only if echo the script like inline of my php codes ..."